# Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E_X(g(X,Y))=E(g(X,Y)|Y).$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables and let $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a non-negative measurable function. If you like assume that $g(X,Y)$ has finite expectation. Let
$$E_X(g(X,Y))=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x,Y)dP_X(x),$$
where $P_X=P\circ X^{-1}$ is the distribution of $X.$

I am interested in the relationship between $E_X(g(X,Y))$ and $E(g(X,Y)|Y).$ I suspect that the following holds:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then 
>   $$E_X(g(X,Y))=E(g(X,Y)|Y).\tag{*}$$

Since I don't have a lot of experience writing proofs with measure-theoretic arguments it would be nice if someone with more experience could have a look at this proof I wrote:

Proof.

In order to show $(*)$ we need to verify

1. $E_X(g(X,Y))$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable
2. $\forall A\in\sigma(Y)$ we have
   $$E[1_A E_X(g(X,Y))] = E[1_A g(X,Y)].$$

Regarding 1.:

It is 
$$E_X(g(X,Y))=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x,Y)dP_X(x)=h(Y),$$ 
where $h(y)=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x,y)dP_X(x)$ is a measurable function. Hence $E_X(g(X,Y))$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

Regarding 2.:

Let $A\in\sigma(Y).$ Note that $1_A$ can be written as $1_A=f(Y)$ for some measurable function $f.$ Moreover, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it holds that 
$$P_{(X,Y)}=P_{X}\otimes P_{Y}.$$
Now write
\begin{align}
E[1_A g(X,Y)] &= \int_\Omega 1_A g(X,Y) dP\\
              &= \int_\Omega f(Y) g(X,Y) dP\\
              &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(y) g(x,y) dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\\
              &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(y) g(x,y) d(P_{X}\otimes P_{Y})(x,y)\\
              &= \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} f(y) g(x,y) dP_{X}(x) dP_{Y}(y) \quad\text{by Fubini}\\
              &= \int_{\mathbb R}f(y) \int_{\mathbb R}  g(x,y) dP_{X}(x) dP_{Y}(y)\\
              &= \int_{\mathbb R}f(y) h(y) dP_{Y}(y)\\
              &= \int_\Omega f(Y) h(Y) dP\\
              &= \int_\Omega 1_A  E_X(g(X,Y)) dP\\
              &= E[1_A  E_X(g(X,Y))].\\
\end{align}

Comment: Your proof looks fine. Just want to point out that Fubini/Tonelli is applicable because $f$ is actually non-negative.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: Nothing to add. Well done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define the function $g (y) = E[f(X,y)]$. Show that $g$ is Borel-measurable, and that $E[f (X,Y)|Y=y] = g(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866063/define-the-function-g-y-efx-y-show-that-g-is-borel-measurable-and)